# PowerShell Export Pfx from Azure Key Vault using Az.KeyVault

Tags: azure, powershell, certificate

I am creating a certificate inside Azure Key Vault and then attempting to export it with private key as a PFX.

```
# Create new Certificate in Key Vault
$policy = New-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SecretContentType "application/x-pkcs12" -SubjectName "CN=contoso" -IssuerName "Self" -ValidityInMonths 12 -ReuseKeyOnRenewal -KeySize 4096 -KeyType 'RSA-HSM';
Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName -Name $ADServicePrincipalCertificateName -CertificatePolicy $policy;

# From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-5.8.0
# Export new Key Vault Certificate as PFX
$securePassword = "fBoFXYD%dg^Q" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force; # This is a throwaway password
$certificate = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName -Name $ADServicePrincipalCertificateName;
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificate.Name -AsPlainText;
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secret)
$x509Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($secretByte, "", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
$type = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pfx
$pfxFileByte = $x509Cert.Export($type, $securePassword);
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\Repos\Certificate.pfx", $pfxFileByte)
Get-PnPAzureCertificate -Path "C:\Repos\Certificate.pfx" -Password $securePassword
```

However, the PFX file is not valid

**Error with Get-PnPAzureCertificate**

[image: Error with Get-PnPAzureCertificate]

**Error with Certificate Import**

[image: Error with Certificate Import]

Any ideas? Using Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate is not an option because there's a bug with it in environments that have policies that forces key lengths

Also, might be worth mentioning that I am using PowerShell 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, we need to change keytype as `RSA` when we create cert policy.

For example

```
$VaultName=""
$ADServicePrincipalCertificateName=""
$policy = New-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SecretContentType "application/x-pkcs12" `
   -SubjectName "CN=contoso.com" -IssuerName "Self" `
   -ValidityInMonths 12 -ReuseKeyOnRenewal `
   -KeySize 4096 -KeyType 'RSA';
Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName -Name $ADServicePrincipalCertificateName -CertificatePolicy $policy;

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
# From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-5.8.0
# Export new Key Vault Certificate as PFX
$securePassword = "fBoFXYD%dg^Q" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force; # This is a throwaway password
$certificate = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName -Name $ADServicePrincipalCertificateName;
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificate.Name -AsPlainText;
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secret)
$x509Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($secretByte, "", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
$type = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pfx
$pfxFileByte = $x509Cert.Export($type, $securePassword);
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("E:\Certificate.pfx", $pfxFileByte)
Get-PnPAzureCertificate -Path "E:\Certificate.pfx" -Password $securePassword
```

[image]

Comment: 100% correct, thank you. The PK requirement is listed in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate